# Reference on periodic Besov spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, besov-space

I am looking for a reference for the construction and the study of the main properties of Besov spaces on the torus (i.e. $\mathrm{B}_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{T}^d))$.

Indeed, I know the classical $\mathrm{B}_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ on the whole space and I would like to know if the theory is the same when we have periodicity. This is mainly a bibliographic question since I think the construction is quite the same, replacing Fourier transform by Fourier series (but I wonder if we could easily 'deduce' the periodic case from the euclidean case).

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the first two references below on MSE or maybe MO somewhere but where exactly eludes me. Regardless: first, there is a set of notes by [Gubinelli and Perkowski](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00157.pdf),

> We will use Littlewood–Paley blocks to obtain a decomposition of distributions into an infinite series of smooth functions. Of course, we have already such a decomposition at our disposal: $f = \sum_k \hat f(k)e^*_k$. But it turns out to be convenient not to consider each
> Fourier coefficient separately, but to work with projections on dyadic Fourier blocks.

Secondly, there is Chapter 3 'Periodic Spaces' of Schmeisser and Triebel's book [ST]. Schmeisser and Triebel do not deduce the periodic case from the euclidean case, but reprove each theorem.

More recently I have stumbled upon a paper [DHWX] of Dai, Hu, Wu, and Xiao that (re?)develops the theory they need and then applies it to a certain PDE called the Boussinesq equation.

I have read none of these carefully, but I hope they are useful to you.

---

[ST] *Schmeisser, Hans-Jürgen; Triebel, Hans*, Topics in Fourier analysis and function spaces, Chichester: John Wiley & Sons. 300 p.; \textsterling 23.95 (1987). [ZBL0661.46025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0661.46025).

[DHWX] *Dai, Yichen; Hu, Weiwei; Wu, Jiahong; Xiao, Bei*, [**The Littlewood-Paley decomposition for periodic functions and applications to the Boussinesq equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0219530519500234), Anal. Appl., Singap. 18, No. 4, 639-682 (2020). [ZBL1444.42023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1444.42023).